# How replace a word in a text file using a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, txtextcontrol

I am new to the bat scripting, so I'm planning to change a word in a text file called "sampleFile.txt"

Can anyone help me? Thankx :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the batch file below like this example, to replace `apple` with `orange` in `file.txt` and write the changes into `newfile.txt`

```
changefile.bat "apple" "orange" "file.txt" >"newfile.txt"
```

Check [DOS Batch - Find and Replace](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace):

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Comment: Look at the changed answer above.